# What is the exact Order of execution in yii framework?

Tags: yii

What is the exact Order of execution in yii framework?

here, I mean detailed explanation from the moment we enter url in address bar.

How actions in a Controller get executed & when?

Comment: Find an IDE that includes a debugger, use it to step over the code leading to the action...

Comment: it is not that easy, it is a complicated process, and depends on the application, it does not make much sense to know the whole proces, but you can surely find a basic application flow on the Yii homepage

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking of basic workflow of yii app then yii definivtive guide can help you.Here is typical workflow taken from the yii definitive guide.
[image]
[Model-View-Controller (MVC)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc)

If you want the actual workflow of your specific app then you can use logging.

Answer (score 3):

Within a for standard controller, the order of execution for standard methods are:

behaviors,
init,
accessRules,
beforeAction,

Those are the ones I mostly am concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

Enable logging
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging
to see exactly what gets executed and in what order.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the urlmanager of Yii you will see a bit how it works.

```
'urlManager' => array(
   //somethings
   'rules' => array(
      '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',  //first rule
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>', //second rule
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>', //third rule
    ) 
);
```

After the base url you will have the controller, if the next thing is an integer (`<id:\d+>`) if will send the request to the view action of the controller. (first rule)

The second rule states that any request with a word and a integer (`<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>`) will be send to the action with the requested id. For example: `http://example/post/update/123` if will be send to the `actionUpdate` of the `PostController` with `$_GET['id'] == 123`.

The third rule is the same as above but with no id. So for example the index and admin action will show a list or a grid with all records